# Issue creating data extension from contact builder

Tags: marketing-cloud

In contact builder, when attempting to create a data extension from existing and having edited some fields I receive this error when clicking "Complete":

> An error occurred attempting to save the new data extension. Contact
>   Global Support for additional assistance regarding this error.

Do you have any insight as to why I may be receiving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the same DE with the same configurations and values from Email Studio instead of Contact Builder solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is helpful but when I was facing this issue it was due to multiple roles assigned to my user, including 2 custom roles. When I reach out to support they explain that  as each standard role has a fixed permission set, hence, when a user is assigned multiple roles these permissions conflict with each other and because of this issue some of the functionalities in Marketing Cloud may not work properly for your user.

If you are indeed looking to have completely functionality in Marketing Cloud, please assign only these Admin roles to your user:

1. Administrator
2. Marketing Cloud Administrator

If you remove all the extra roles already assigned to your user and only assign the above 2 roles this should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you use any email domain which are not been agreed and verified from your SFMC account. If you replace it with Google mail account. The error will be rectified

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).